# ESB WSO2 Endpoint Dynamics NAV 2013

Tags: web-services, wso2, esb, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav-2013

I'm trying to create an EndPoint to use Dynamics NAV web services. 
The problem is that the path to the WSDL

```
http://remotehost:7047/DynamicsNAV70/WS/SystemService?wsdl
```

is protected with NTLM and I can not access. 
Anyone know how to pass the username and password? 
thanks

Comment: I suppose all the endpoints specified in WSDL is also secured with username and password. Am I correct?

Comment: Hi Rafa, Thanks for confirming. I will check on this and get back to you.

Comment: I heard that this can be done using custom mediator. I'm afraid, I don't have much experience with NTLM and I'm unable to provide an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your Service Tier with **WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication** = **true** ([Details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from/)) you will be able to access the Web Service WSDL with [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and a valid Windows User Account (DOMAIN\username) who has Access to Dynamics NAV.